# Spring Boot Integration Tests - How to run multiple test classes with a single context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

I have a Spring Boot project where I have a couple of api end points defined. I am currently writing integration tests for each of these apis. I annotate my test classes as follows.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
...
```

Now, for each of my test class, a new context is set up for executing them and it takes time. I prefer to keep the test cases for each of my api end points in separate classes for organizing them logically, but I don't want my test execution time to shoot up every time I add a new controller class and a corresponding test class. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: if you don't want spring boot to start for each test case, then you need to keep all of them in one class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as your tests use identical contexts (same beans mocked, same configuration) spring will, by default, reuse a suitable context before it creates a new one.

An exception is when you annotate a test with `@DirtiesContext`
This tells the Runner to invalidate the used context.